# wxPython -- Bash shell

Tags: bash, shell, wxpython

Hey I want to create a bash-shell in wxPython, the only thing it should be able to do is run a python file and be able to offer user_input on the fly.
(I know there is a Python Shell, but that is something different)

Can someone help me with this? thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [wxPython: how to create a bash shell window?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/989129/wxpython-how-to-create-a-bash-shell-window)

Comment: Well I don't think so :),  I don't need all the bash features I just need the possibility to run a python file in the way bash does..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use wx.lib.shell

Read more in here -> http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.lib.shell-module.html

Comment: That seems to be good, I don't have the time to check it now though, thanks for the tip anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe pyCrust plus the Python debugger?

Comment: I don't see how I can use pyCrust in this case :s it does not offer something like RunFile() or Open(),...

Comment: You'd probably have to use it in combination with wx.Process or the subprocess module, which is what I expect most of the other editors use.