# how to implement GUI window or a frame for bash shell with wxwidget or wxpython

Tags: python, user-interface, command-line, wxpython, wxwidgets

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [wxPython: how to create a bash shell window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/989129/wxpython-how-to-create-a-bash-shell-window)

HI, guys. I want to develop a window or frame for the bash shell program. 
Even after trials with the code of the link given by **Bryan** (thank you so much!!), it still does not work.

Basically, I use the code sample put by Anurag Uniyal. However, I have to deal with several processes (so one window for one subprocess call). I do not know how to create a customeried interpretor object with my application data passed. Each time, the python compiler complain about the constructor function. Otherwise, I have to make an new interpretor class (not instance) for each application, which is not good.

```
MyInterpretor(mydata)#ctor error
wx.py.shell.Shell(parent=self, InterpClass=MyInterpretor)

class MyInterpretor(object):
    def __init__(self, my_data, locals, rawin, stdin, stdout, stderr):

        self.application=my_data
        self.introText = "Welcome to " + self.application.name + "!"
        self.locals = locals
        self.revision = 1.0
        self.rawin = rawin
        self.stdin = stdin
        self.stdout = stdout
        self.stderr = stderr

        self.more = False
        origWD = os.getcwd()
        os.chdir(self.application.dir)            

        # bash process
        self.bp = Popen(self.application.cmd, shell=False, stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)

        # start output grab thread
        self.outputThread = BashProcessThread(self.bp.stdout.readline)
        self.outputThread.start()

        # start err grab thread
        self.errorThread = BashProcessThread(self.bp.stderr.readline)
        self.errorThread.start()
        os.chdir(origWD)
```

actually I just want a textctrl to input/output with a background process stdin/stdout.
but this wx.py.shell.Shell approach seems to heavy for me, let alone it does not work.

lyrae's code of the link looks right direction. but the code, as pointed by Bryan, cannot work with multiple times command input(Broken pipe error).

Comment: Hi, Bryan, please see my revision and comments. Thank you so much

Comment: This isn't specific to what you asked for, but have you considered using [Dabo](http://www.dabodev.com/)? It's a dektop application framework built with Python and supports wxPython.