# python + gtk3 on windows?

Tags: python, windows, terminal, wxwidgets, gtk3

I'm trying to port a small app to windows (I made it for ubuntu initally), it's written on python + gtk3... I know that gtk3 is hard to make it work on windows (even on c++), but is it possible to make it work on Windows with Python?

I do not want to re-write it on another toolkit, and if so, it will probably be `wxWidgets`, because I'm using an embedded terminal on it (`Vte.Terminal()`), that IIRC is part of gtk3 too.

If it's not possible, is there a way to make a terminal widget on `wxPython` in Windows?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Id doesn't look like you can use gtk3 on windows quite yet, although it looks like development for such is very active at this point [link](http://blogs.gnome.org/alexl/2011/11/25/gtk-work-on-windows/). You may also want to check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006689/where-can-i-download-precompiled-gtk-3-binaries-or-windows-installer) because it may help with your gtk3 question.
In response to your question on whether you can create a terminal in wxPython, you'll want to look up [this project](http://www.sivachandran.in/2008/04/termemulator-10-released.html) and check out [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/989129/wxpython-how-to-create-a-bash-shell-window). Also, a very similar question to what yours sounds like was asked [here](http://www.python-forum.org/pythonforum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=24036). Please let me know if that doesn't help!

Comment: That terminal widget works, but not on windows (i've used it before), and the other two links seem to refer to a bash shell (again, linux, not windows)... i ended up using `pyqt` and poping out the windows command prompt with `subprocess.Popen()`, thanks for the answer anyway... it seems like i'ts impossible to embedd command prompt terminal on window$...

Answer (score 1):

Gtk3 works fine on windows, there is an unofficial .exe from a french man site: http://www.tarnyko.net

I'm developing with gtk3 on windows in this moment, I use gtk 3.6.1.

Answer (score 0):

I think, the best way is installing python and gtk3 with msys2.
firstly install msys2 and install python and gtk3 using msys2. search on Google "how to install python gobject to msys2"